# How to modify a line in a file using Python

Tags: python

I am trying to do what for many will be a very straight forward thing but for me is just infuriatingly difficult.
I am trying search for a line in a file that contains certain words or phrases and modify that line...that's it. 
I have been through the forum and suggested similar questions and have found many hints but none do just quite what I want or are beyond my current ability to grasp.

This is the test file:

```
# 1st_word  2nd_word

# 3rd_word  4th_word
```

And this is my script so far:

```
############################################################
file = 'C:\lpthw\\text'
f1 = open(file, "r+")
f2 = open(file, "r+")
############################################################

def wrline():
    lines = f1.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if "1st_word" in line and "2nd_word" in line:
            #f2.write(line.replace('#\t', '\t'))
            f2.write((line.replace('#\t', '\t')).rstrip())
    f1.seek(0)

wrline()
```

My problem is that the below inserts a \n after the line every time and adds a blank line to the file.

```
f2.write(line.replace('#\t', '\t'))
```

The file becomes:

```
    1st_word    2nd_word


#   3rd_word    4th_word
```

An extra blank line between the lines of text.

If I use the following:

```
f2.write((line.replace('#\t', '\t')).rstrip())
```

I get this:

```
    1st_word    2nd_wordd

#   3rd_word    4th_word
```

No new blank line inserted but and extra "d" at the end instead.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not closed the files and there is no need for the `\t`

Also get rid of the `rstrip()`

Read in the file, replace the data and write it back.. open and close each time.

```
fn = 'example.txt'
new_data = []

# Read in the file
with open(fn, 'r+') as file:
    filedata = file.readlines()

# Replace the target string
for line in filedata:
    if "1st_word" in line and "2nd_word" in line:
        line = line.replace('#', '')
    new_data.append(line)

# Write the file out again
with open(fn, 'w+') as file:
    for line in new_data:
        file.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would keep read and write operations separate.

```
#read
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

#parse, change and write back
with open(file, 'w') as f:
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith('#\t'):
            line = line[1:]
    f.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your blank line is coming from the original blank line in the file. Writing a line with nothing in it writes a newline to the file. Instead of not putting anything into the written line, you have to completely skip the iteration, so it does not write that newline. Here's what I suggest:

```
def wrline():
    lines = open('file.txt', 'r').readlines()
    f2 = open('file.txt', 'w')
    for line in lines:
        if '1st_word' in line and '2nd_word' in line:
            f2.write((line.replace('# ', ' ')).rstrip('\n'))
        else:
            if line != '\n':
                f2.write(line)
    f2.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But tried as you suggested and out put was this:

 1st_word 2nd_word# 3rd_word 4th_word_word

Comment: Then remove the `.rstrip()`, so that there is a newline between then